# Visual Studio 2015 comment shortcut doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, comments

When I first installed VS2015 I could comment out code with Ctrl + k. 
Now it's stopped working, I've reset keyboard mapping, I've reassigned it to a different shortcut but nothing works. Can anyone help? it's such an annoying issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Belatedly...

In Visual Studio 2017 Community <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> does this action instead of just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment.

According to this binding list, that must have changed at some point for VS 2015;

https://shortcutworld.com/Visual-Studio/win/Visual-Studio_2015_Shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Go on Tools ->

1. Import and Export Settings Wizard
2. Reset all settings
3. Choose your Language and environment (C#, WEB, ...)

It will reset all keyboard shortcut to the correct map.

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant, this could be a sign that there is a collision in the shortcut itself. E.g., the shortcut is used by multiple commands